# Как реализовать отображение компонента из массива компонентов?

Tags: reactjs

Имеется массив из нескольких компонентов, выводимых на экран.

Я сделал две функции, которые меняют индекс (+ и -), и функцию что возвращает элемент массива, согласно индексу.

Однако при нажатии, компонент не выводится на экран, и пропадает первый компонент, выводившийся по дефолту. Меж тем, console.log выводиться: **$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)**.

```js
const pages = [<Comp/>, <Comp2 />, <Comp3 />];

let index = 0;

const [page, setPage] = useState(pages[0]);

const rightHandler = () => {
  if (index >= pages.length - 1) return;
  index++;
  showPosition();
};

const leftHandler = () => {
  if (index <= 0) return;
  index--;
  showPosition();
};

function showPosition() {
  return pages[index];
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём я ошибся?

Answer (score 0):

Вы вызываете функцию **showPosition**, которая возвращает какое то значение, однако вы не сохраняете возвращенный результат и никак его не обрабатываете.

Вам необходимо в функции, которая предназначена для смены компонента, не возвращать значение, сохранять его в состоянии компонента в переменную `page`.

```
function showPosition() {
    setPage(pages[index]);
}
```

В таком случае, React поймет, что состояние компонента было изменено и требуется его перерисовать.

З.Ы.: Да и переменную **index** лучше в стейт положить, а изменение **index** отслеживать через **useEffect** и там уже менять **page**

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(pages[0]);
const [index, setIdx] = useState(0);

const rightHandler = () => {
    if (index >= pages.length - 1) return;
    setIdx(++index);
};

const leftHandler = () => {
    if (index <= 0) return;
    setIdx(--index);
};

useEffect(() => {
    setPage(pages[index]);
}, [index]);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!